# How can I sort the keys of a Map in Java?

Tags: java

This is a very basic question, I'm just not that good with Java.  I have a Map and I want to get a list or something of the keys in sorted order so I can iterate over them.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use a [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is an implementation of the `SortedMap` interface. It presents its keys in sorted order.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
/* Add entries to the map in any order. */
...
/* Now, iterate over the map's contents, sorted by key. */
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

If you are working with another Map implementation that isn't sorted as you like, you can pass it to the [constructor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Map)) of `TreeMap` to create a new map with sorted keys.

```
void process(Map<String, Object> original) {
  Map<String, Object> copy = new TreeMap<String, Object>(original);
  /* Now use "copy", which will have keys in sorted order. */
  ... 
}
```

A `TreeMap` works with any type of key that implements the `Comparable` interface, putting them in their "natural" order. For keys that aren't `Comparable`, or whose natural ordering isn't what you need, you can implement your own [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and specify that in the [constructor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: The code I'm consuming gives me a Map object, so how do I then convert it into a TreeMap or use a TreeMap to do the sorting?

Comment: You can create the TreeMap using a constructor whose parameter is any Map.  Also, congratulations erickson (I assume, since you're only 5 rep away from 10k).

Comment: You would better off sorting keys (place in a TreeSet) then calling get on the original Map. Creating a new TreeMap results in everything getting rehashed.

Comment: Steve, that's incorrect. No hashing occurs with a TreeMap; it's a red-black tree. Anyway, a TreeSet delegates to an internal TreeMap, so creating a TreeSet, iterating over its keys, and using them to perform an O(log(n)) lookup in another tree would be confusing and inefficient.

Answer (score 39):

You have several options. Listed in order of preference:

1. Use a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):
   `SortedMap<whatever> myNewMap = new TreeMap<whatever>(myOldMap);`
   This is vastly preferable if you want to iterate more than once. It keeps the keys sorted so you don't have to sort them before iterating.
2. There is no #2.
3. There is no #3, either.
4. `SortedSet<whatever> keys = new TreeSet<whatever>(myMap.keySet());`
5. `List<whatever> keys = new ArrayList<whatever>(myMap.keySet());
   Collections.sort(keys);`

The last two will get you what you want, but should only be used if you only want to iterate once and then forget the whole thing.

Comment: In step #4, you could also create a TreeSet (a sorted set) instead of a list, which saves you from making an explicit call to sort().

Comment: @David: I did think of that, but for some reason I forgot that it was possible to iterate over a Set. It does require sorting every time, though.

Comment: hmm i like the #4 . why does it require more sorting than #1 ? i would have thought it was equally good

Comment: @litb: If you're dumping the map into a TreeMap every time you want to iterate over it, then you're right, they are the same.

Comment: #4 isn't as good as #1 if you need the values from the map too. Iterating over entries saves the extra lookup for the value.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a sorted collection when iterating but it make more sense to have a sorted map in the first place. (As has already been suggested)

All the same, here is how you do it.

```
Map<String, Object> map;
for(String key: new TreeSet<String>(map.keySet()) {
  // accessed in sorted order.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the methods mentioned in other answers, with Java 8 streams, another shorthand to get a sorted key list from a map would be -

```
List<T> sortedKeys = myMap.keySet().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

One could actually get stuff done after `.sorted()` as well (like using a `.map(...)` or a `.forEach(...)`), instead of collecting it in the list and then iterating over the list.