# What is 'natural ordering' in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort the keys of a Map in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571388/how-can-i-sort-the-keys-of-a-map-in-java)

In class `TreeMap` the Java API says:

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

What is meant by natural ordering ? A class used as key does not have to implement the `Comparable` interface, but what ordering will be used instead ?

Comment: The point of my question is to understand the term 'natural ordering', not how to sort the keys of a Map in general.

Comment: For an integer, natural order mean ascending order and for strings, alphabetical order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were to try this yourself you'd find that you cannot use a `TreeMap` that has a `K` that does not implement `Comparable` (Unless you explicitly provide a `Comparator` via the `TreeMap` constructor).

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        TreeMap<App,String> tm = new TreeMap<App,String>();
        tm.put(new App(), "value");
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: App cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

The javadoc for `put()` states this explicitly:

> **Throws:** 
>   ClassCastException - if the specified key cannot be compared with the keys currently in the map

The link in [javadocs for TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for "Natural Ordering" takes you to the `Comparable` interface

Answer (score 5):

"Natural" ordering is the ordering implied by the implementation of the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface by the objects used as keys in the `TreeMap`. Essentially, RBTree must be able to tell which key is smaller than the other key, and there are two ways to supply that logic to the RBTree implementation:

- Implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in the class(es) used as keys to `TreeMap`, or
- Supply an implementation of the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that would do comparing outside the key class itself.

Answer (score 4):

It **is** a requirement to implement `Comparable`.  It's just not enforced at compile time.

```
jamlong% cat Wah.java

import java.util.*; 

public class Wah {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Wah, Integer> wah = new TreeMap<Wah, Integer>(); 
        wah.put(new Wah(), 1); 
        wah.put(new Wah(), 2);
    } 
}

jamlong% java Wah

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Wah cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:542)
    at Wah.main(Wah.java:8)
```

When in doubt, [read the `TreeMap` source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html). Line 541, for instance.

Comment: *"It IS a requirement to implement Comparable."* - It is NOT a hard requirement.  If you instantiate the `TreeMap` with a `Comparator`, the keys don't need to implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @StephenC - I certainly could have been more clear in my wording, but the question was basically asking in the context of the "Natural Ordering", which would only apply if you're not using a TreeMap instantiated with a Comparator in the first place (or, I suppose, if you explicitly instantiated with a Comparator which gave the Natural Ordering - but that would make the question rather nonsensical), in which case, my answer stands - it doesn't enforce that the class is Comparable, but it will ClassCastException at runtime if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Natural ordering is just the order provided by the `Comparable` interface. You can create a `TreeMap` without a `Comparator`, but then any attempt to put any keys that do not implement a natural order will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

The natural ordering is determined by the keys.

So if you use a String you'll get one ordering; Integer will give another.

I think Comparable is a requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I can create a TreeMap object with a self-made class which does not implement the Comparable interface. At least, I get no errors. The API also makes no restrictions to the key generic type.

Comment: So what ordering do you get?  This is the best way to answer such questions: Let the JVM tell you.

Comment: Yes and no. I want to know the correct answer, not a test-generated answer which could possibly give me a false impression :-)