# Exception: javax.swing.KeyStroke cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable? Need a reason for this error

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on an enterprise application. It was working fine earlier when the system had JDK1.6.+.
I upgraded my JDK to 1.7.+.
After that, I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.KeyStroke cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
```

Although I have solved my problem by switching between the JDK versions. I want to understand why the error is coming after upgrading to JDK 7. Obviously, there would be some changes in the implementation.But I want to understand that.
I tried to check the Documentation of keystroke class. But I got nothing related to this.

Can someone explain this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jarrod: This question doesn't have any answer.
I asked the reason for why it's working when app is running with JDK 1.6 and not with JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeMap` requires the key class to be orderable because it creates a tree of keys that are ordered. So you need to provide a way of ordering the keys, either via natural ordering (i.e., implementing the `Comparable` interface in the key class) or via a comparator class provided at `TreeMap` construction time.

`KeyStroke` does not implement `Comparable` and therefore does not provide natural ordering. This is the reason for the error. Simply provide a Comparator implementation that takes care of providing a way of ordering the keys, for example (ordering by keycode):

```
map = new TreeMap<KeyStroke, YourValueClass>(new Comparator<KeyStroke>() {
  public int compare(KeyStroke o1, KeyStroke o2) {
    return o1.getKeyCode() - o2.getKeyCode();
  }
});
```

More info about ordering requirements of `TreeMap`: [How can I sort the keys of a Map in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571388/how-can-i-sort-the-keys-of-a-map-in-java)

How Red-Black Trees (what `TreeMap` is) work, this should clarify why the key needs to be orderable (because it must be determined where to put it in the tree of keys): [Explanation of Red-Black tree based implementation of TreeMap in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329662/explanation-of-red-black-tree-based-implementation-of-treemap-in-java/21331561#21331561)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, by that, do we mean that JDK 6, has the comparator available?

Answer (score 0):

Why a TreeMap requires a class to be Comparable is nicely explained by other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133600/java-cannot-cast-to-comparable-when-using-treemap).

The other answers do not explain why you have the problem after changing from Java 6+ to Java 7+. The behavior of TreeMap is the same for Java 6 and 7 (I checked it in my IDE). Maybe your code uses another implementation in Java 7 due to Depency Injection. Just a guess. Could you check how your map is instantiated?